# WordPress add filter

Tags: wordpress

I try to change the excerpt length using a filter.

The theme supports a filter to change the except length. The source code is as follows:

```
$content = get_the_content();
                            echo apply_filters( 'theme_standard_post_content_list', wp_trim_words( $content, 55 ) );
```

I tried the following add filter, but it does not work:

```
add_filter('theme_standard_post_content_list', 'plugin_myContentFilter');
function plugin_myContentFilter($content)
  {
     return wp_trim_words( $content, 220 ); 
  }
```

Did I miss something?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't extend the length of the content, at that point, since it has already been reduced to 55 characters...

Comment: @mevius. By referring to your comment, I redefined $content and now it works well. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At that point length of content is already reduced to 55 characters and can't be extended.

You might redefine `$content` variable.